# How do I make the widget run sequentially in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following code written in a flutter I want to make the pieces run in order (from 1 to the last piece) See the comment on line 34,
how can I Do ?

```
        ....
          SingleChildScrollView(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    child: _clipsWidget(),    // <<< I want to write a code here that allows widgets (widget 1-widget 2....) to be executed in an orderly and sequential manner
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

Widget _clipsWidget1() {
      return Container(
      height: 250,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
         
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
          ....
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              Container(
           ....
              ),
 
  }
  Widget _clipsWidget2() {.....}
  
  Widget _clipsWidget3() {.....}
  
  Widget _clipsWidget4() {.....}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want a list of widgets to appear?

Comment: @nvoigt Yes one by one

Comment: I think what you want is a ListView Widget. Using ListView.builder() you can build widgets sequentially and only need to write the code once to define how that widget structure. If you want I can post an answer on how to use a ListView.

Comment: @AbhishekThulasi I mean they are executed one by one and not arranged horizontally

Comment: The ListView.builder builds it's child one after another. Could you give more details as in what those _clipsWidget return? The structure of _clipsWidget.

Comment: @AbhishekThulasi i have edited my code.

Answer (score 0):

To have multiple widgets arranged below each other, you can use a `Row` widget:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  child: Row(
   children: [
     _clipsWidget1(),
     _clipsWidget2(),
     _clipsWidget3(),
     _clipsWidget4()
   ]
  )
)
```

Comment: I mean they are executed one by one and not arranged horizontally

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea what you want. The code will be executed sequentially, they will be arranged in a squence, I'm not sure what you mean. Do you want an animation?

Comment: @nvoigt I think he means the widget1 will execute first then widget2 and so on. However, I don't understand the main purpose of this... Can't help at all.

Answer (score 0):

Does having to be shown sequentially over time mean that we need animations? Then you should use AnimatedList -> https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedList-class.html

Answer (score 0):

if you need to show first widget for sometime than second widget and so on
then try

```
class _RunOneByOneState extends State<RunOneByOne> {
  final widgets = <Widget>[
    _clipsWidget1(),
    _clipsWidget2(),
    _clipsWidget3(),
    _clipsWidget4()
  ];

  int index = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 20), (timer) {
      if (index != widgets.length - 1) {
        setState(() {
          index++;
        });
      } else {
        timer.cancel();
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: widgets[index],
    );
  }
}
```